# Overview of observations that meet conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements, mean

I have a dataframe of 20.000 observations based on 130 participants. There are several observations from each participant.

I'm calculating the participants' response time.

The average is 25.01.

I want to identify the participants that have an average response time >= 10 seconds.

I can't get my head around this. The ideal output would be a matrix/list of names and their corresponding average response time (but only if it's below 10 seconds).

Comment: Please show a small example data and expected output

Comment: Please give us an output of your data using `str()`and `dput()`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
library("dplyr")
my_data %>% group_by(subject) %>% 
        summarise(avg_response=mean(response_time)) %>%
        filter(avg_response>=10)
```

You could also use `aggregate()` and `subset()` from base R.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm still quite new in r. Thus I'm a bit confused about the % signs in your formula. 

My dataset is called: "Samlet"
The response time is called: "timetoanswer"  (I don't have the average response time on an individual level yet)
Participants: participantcode

Comment: `my_data` above corresponds to `Samlet`; `response_time` corresponds to `timetoanswer`;  `subject` corresponds to `participantcode`.  If you want a more detailed answer, you really need to provide a reproducible example.